# search users in FOSUserundle with like clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserundle and I use this code in order to find a user:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array(
        'username'  =>  'name surname',
    ));
```

it works it the key perfectly match the username, is there a way to use a 'like clause'?

thanks

MY SOLUTION

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findUserByUsernameLike($username)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT u.id, u.username FROM MyUserBundle:User u where u.username LIKE :username ORDER BY u.username ASC'
        )
        ->setParameter('username', '%'.$username.'%')
        ->getResult();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`UserManager::findUserBy()` method is just a proxy for Doctrine's `EntityManager::findOneBy()` which doesn't support `LIKE` expression. You'll have to create a custom DQL query like this:

```
SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u WHERE u.username LIKE :username
```

You could create your own `UserManager` class which would extend `UserManager` provided by FOSUserBundle:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager as BaseManager;

class UserManager extends BaseManager
{
    public function findUserByUsernameLike($username)
    {
       return $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->where('u.username LIKE :username')
           ->setParameter('username', '%' . $username . '%')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Register it as a service derived from `fos_user.user_manager`:

```
<service id="my.user_manager" class="...\UserManager" parent="fos_user.user_manager" />
```

And tell FOSUserBundle to use this class as user manager:

```
# config.yaml

fos_user:
    services:
        user_manager: my.user_manager
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try this solution. at the moment I created  a User entity that extends BaseUser, where is the best place to put the new UserManager class?

Comment: There is no "best place" but something like `...\MyBundle\Model` namepsace might be appropriate.

Comment: I found a similar solution, more easy for my poor symfony knowledge. I created a custom repository class as explained in symfony book and I put a method as suggested by Crozin. thanks you!